# How to translate SQL Outer Apply to Linq

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am having issues trying to convert this SQL statement with Outer Applys to Linq. I have read and tried lots of examples with no luck getting anything to work. Could someone please show me an example of how to write this into a Linq statement?

```
SELECT 
    [P].[BandID],
    [P].[PitchID],
    [P].[PitchName],
    [PRO].[PitchProcessID],
    [PRO].[ProcessDescription],
    [PRO].[IsHighVoltage],
    [TRA].[EmployeeID],
    [TRA].[TrainingID],
    [TRA].[Score]
FROM 
    [dbo].[vwPitch] AS [P]
    OUTER APPLY(SELECT 
                    [PP].[PitchProcessID],
                    [PP].[IsHighVoltage],
                    [PP].[ProcessName] + ' - ' 
                  + [PP].[ProcessDescription] AS [ProcessDescription]
                FROM 
                    [dbo].[vwPitchProcess] AS [PP]
                WHERE
                     [PP].[PitchID] = [P].[PitchID]) AS [PRO]
    OUTER APPLY(SELECT 
                    [T].[TrainingID],
                    [T].[EmployeeID],
                    [E].[FLName],
                    [T].[Score]
                FROM
                    [dbo].[TrainingScore] AS [T]
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[vwEmployee] 
                        AS [E] ON [T].[EmployeeID] = [E].[EmployeeID]
                WHERE
                    [T].[PitchProcessID] = [PRO].[PitchProcessID] 
                        AND [T].[EmployeeID] = 123456) AS [TRA]
WHERE
    [P].[BandID] = 34;
```

Comment: Basically you should be able to replace the `OUTER APPLY` with an `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Can you show your C# code?

Comment: SQL can't be converted into LINQ. At best, you can write LINQ that translates into SQL that returns the same result. For us to be able to help you we need you to show the C# class model and how it is mapped to the database model. BTW, linq-to-sql != entity framework.

Comment: For 'most' SQL statements, there is a Linq or Linq-to-sql equivalent. I just need that equivalent for the statement above. The joins in the above statement should explain how the models are linked and the Fields in the statement are the properties in those models.

Comment: Check this [Collection selector references outer in a non-where case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#collection-selector-references-outer-in-a-non-where-case)

Comment: *I just need , should explain*... It's not that easy. You can't just drop a SQL statement and wait for someone to guess what the LINQ should look like. Also, it's important to know which EF version you're using.